# Filter data based on Object with filter values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have in my app some filters. Whenever I click search, the data should be filtered based on the values of the search. I don't know if there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do in a cooler way or fancy way. The values of the search are being stored the following way:

```
FORM_VALUES =
   {
     title: '',
     name: 'John',
     Age: 56
    }
```

If the value of the objects are empty `''` then I shouldn't considered them when i filter the array of objects.
My array of Objects looks like this:

```
[
 {
   title:'CEO',
   name: 'John',
   Age: 56
 },
 {
   title: null,
   name: 'George',
   Age: 56
 },
]
```

**In this example, it should return the first element of the array.**

**My code:**

```
data.filter(d => {
     if ((d.title === FORM_VALUES.title || FORM_VALUES.title === '')
        && (d.name === FORM_VALUES.name || FORM_VALUES.name === '')
        && (d.age === FORM_VALUES.age || FORM_VALUES.age === '')) {
           return d;
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter` to get the people with the values, and use `Object.keys` and `delete` to remove any empty entries, and `every` with `Object.entries` to find the actual objects:

```js
const FORM_VALUES = {
  title: '',
  name: 'John',
  Age: 56
}

const data = [{
    title: 'CEO',
    name: 'John',
    Age: 56
  },
  {
    title: null,
    name: 'George',
    Age: 56
  }
];

let searchObj = { ...FORM_VALUES };
Object.keys(searchObj).forEach(key => searchObj[key] == "" ? delete searchObj[key] : key);

const found = data.filter(d => Object.entries(searchObj).every(([k, v]) => d[k] == v));
console.log(found);
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my question. Your answer will only return one value correct? It should return an array. In the example I provided it only return the first value because it was the only one that matched the search criterias

Comment: Edited @yayfubofubo.

Answer (score 0):

Get an array of key/value pairs from the `FORM_VALUES` object with `Object.entries()`. Iterate the array of pairs with `Array.every()` for each pair, return `true` if the value `''` (empty string) or value of the filter matches with that of the current object.

```js
const FORM_VALUES = {"title":"","name":"John","Age":56}

const data = [{"title":"CEO","name":"John","Age":56},{"title":null,"name":"George","Age":56}]

const result = data.filter(o =>
  Object.entries(FORM_VALUES)
    .every(([k, v]) => v === '' || o[k] === v)
)

console.log(result)
```